# Strange output from class statement

Tags: ruby

I am trying to place 3 values into each index of an array. The values are for the `class`, `assignment`, and `grade`. They come from a class object called `Grade_Log`.

I am running into an issue with the output.

```
class Grade_Log
  attr_accessor :which_class, :assignment_type, :grade
  def initialize(which_class, assignment_type, grade)
    @which_class = which_class
    @assignment_type = assignment_type
    @grade = grade
  end
end

#values are assigned to add_class, add_assignment, and add_grade

  grade_index[grade_index_tally] = Grade_Log.new(add_class,add_assignment,add_grade)

  puts grade_index[grade_index_tally]
```

I would like for it to output, for example, `"PHYSICS, HOMEWORK, 95"`, but instead I am getting the following. `#<Grade_Log:0x0000000002baaa20>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to `puts` an instance of your `Grade_Log` class, you'll need to define `to_s` for your class. Right now, it's likely using the default `to_s` method.

I think you'd want something like this:

```
class Grade_Log
  ... # your code 

  def to_s
    "#{which_class}, #{assignment_type}, #{grade}"
  end
end
```

Which is basically the same thing as:

```
def to_s
  [which_class, assignment_type, grade].join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a `Grade_Log` object, the initialize method is called and the parameters are assigned to attributes:

```
tmp = GradeLog.new("PHYSICS", "HOMEWORK", 95)
```

---

If you simply `puts` the variable you get the object information:

```
puts tmp #=> #<Grade_Log:0x007fc27213f3a8>
```

To access the attributes you should do

```
puts tmp.which_class #=> PHYSICS
puts tmp.assignment_type #=> HOMEWORK
puts tmp.grade #=> 95
```

A **fast way to see the object content** is the `inspect` method:

```
puts tmp.inspect #=> #<Grade_Log:0x007fd7e6917358 @which_class="PHYSICS", @assignment_type="HOMEWORK", @grade=95>
```

which is the same as using [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p):

```
p tmp #=> #<Grade_Log:0x007fd7e6917358 @which_class="PHYSICS", @assignment_type="HOMEWORK", @grade=95>
```

---

Another option is to **access the instance variables**, [Object.html#instance_variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) and [Object.html#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
tmp.instance_variables.map { |v| tmp.instance_variable_get(v) } #=> ["PHYSICS", "HOMEWORK", 95]
```

Or define a custom method inside your class, to get the array of values, for example (no need to edit the method when a new attribute is added):

```
def attributes_values
  instance_variables.map { |v| instance_variable_get(v) }
end
```

So you can call just

```
tmp.attributes_values #=> ["PHYSICS", "HOMEWORK", 95]
```

---

Finally, if you want **format the output as a string** you could define a `to_s` method to override the default [Object#to_s](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s) method, to call `puts tmp`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, picked up the suggestion.